# Goggle sheets linking different sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Using Google Drive can I link a whole worksheet from a shared with me file to insert it as a sheet into a workbook that I created in my drive.

I don't want to link cell range values, I want the whole sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by "linking" you mean read the values from another spreadsheet and update them, you could use IMPORTRANGE. If works for a single cell or a range of values, but there a some limits. For details, se the related questions.

Related

- [How do I link a cell in Google Spreadsheets to a cell in another document?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/786/88163)
- [How to work around the IMPORTRANGE error: "Results too large"?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/88520/88163)